Repeating rows in data after joining 3rd table to an existing join
I am using a stored procedure to bring back data from some different tables and I do not have the tables joined correctly. To start I am bringing back CommentID, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, CommentText from a table called Comments. I am bringing back Username from a table called tblUser. This works great but I run into an issue when trying to add two fields called DaysDQ and DQAmount from a table called WorkFlowMap.
This is my select and join clauses. After added the DQ fields it will repeat every comment with every possible value for DQAmount and DaysDQ.
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@RecordLimit)
    c.CommentId,
    c.CreatedDate AS 'Created Date',
    c.ModifiedDate AS 'Modified Date',
    c.CommentText AS 'Comment Text',
    u.Username AS 'User Name',
wm.DaysDQ,
wm.DQAmount

FROM Collections.Comment c
INNER JOIN Collections.CommentMap cm ON c.CommentId = cm.CommentId -- Join Comment Map with Comments on CommentID
INNER JOIN Collections.WorkflowMap wm ON cm.ObjectId = wm.ObjectId
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblUser u ON c.CreatedByID = u.UserID -- Join with dbo.tblUser
WHERE cm.ObjectId IN (SELECT AccountID FROM @AccountIds)
  AND CreatedDate >= COALESCE(@MinDate, CreatedDate)
  AND CreatedDate <= COALESCE(@MaxDate, CreatedDate)
  AND (c.CommentText IS NOT NULL AND LTRIM(RTRIM(c.CommentText)) <> '') -- Filter out rows where CommentText is null or contains only whitespace
ORDER BY c.CreatedDate DESC;

Below are my results and below that are the expected results.



Hi - please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text appropriately formatted. If a join results in more/incorrect data then your join definition is incorrect - so all you need to do is examine your data and determine the correct join definition. What’s the specific issue you are facing?
